# Identity of believers at the rapture

Tags: righteousness

At the rapture, how will God identify those who have received His righteousness? Is it just because He knows those who are His? Are those who have received His righteousness now qualified for heaven?

> Matt 24:40-42 - Two men will be in the field: one will be taken and
> the other left. Two women will be grinding at the mill: one will be
> taken and the other left. Therefore keep watch, because you do not
> know the day on which your Lord will come.

Comment: Welcome to BH. On this site we look at the meanings of words. We usually need a Bible reference to work on. If you can edit in one please do. Perhaps you could add in asking what "knows" means in 2 Timothy 2:19? Do read the tour[below, left] to see how this site works.

Answer (score 2):

The Matthew 24 text quoted is a good one, as it clearly speaks of events on the unexpected day when Christ, our Lord, will return. And yes, those whom the Lord identifies as his own, have the righteousness of God evaluated unto them. They are taken to be with him in glory. Other related texts show that they will join the 'dead in Christ', now with him in the heavens, forming part of the vast 'army' of angels who are with Christ at the start of that awesome Day of Resurrection and Judgment (e.g. 1 Thessalonians 4:13-5:3 & 2 Thessalonians 1:5-10).

The Matthew 24 text is also linked to further information in Revelation, and it is the following verses that directly answer your question. It is chapter 14, the time for the vision to be fulfilled identified by an angel as the hour of God's judgment.

> "If any man worship the beast and his image, and receive his mark in
> the forehead or in his hand, the same shall drink of the wine of the
> wrath of God... Here is the patience of the saints; here are they that
> keep the commandments of God, and the faith of Jesus.
>
> And I heard a voice from heaven saying unto me, Write, Blessed are the
> dead which die in the Lord from henceforth. Yea, saith the Spirit,
> that they may rest from their labours, and their works do follow them.
> And I looked, and behold, a white cloud, and upon the cloud one sat
> like unto the Son of man, having on his head a golden crown, and in
> his hand  sharp sickle.
>
> And another angel came out of the temple, crying with a loud voice to
> him that sat on the cloud, Thrust in thy sickle and reap: for the time
> is come for thee to reap; for the harvest of the earth is ripe."
> Revelation 14:9-16 A.V.

Immediately after that first reaping comes a second reaping, but this time the ones gathered by that (different) heavenly one are cast into the winepress of the wrath of God, to be tormented forever. The believers, to whom is evaluated the righteousness of God, have been safely gathered into Christ's 'barn' (Matthew 13:24-30 & 36-43). But the 'weeds' sown by the evil one in amongst the children of the kingdom ('the good seed') are pulled out by angels to be cast into the furnace.

One harvest, two reapings.

So, **how does God identify "the children of the kingdom"?** They ***do not*** have the mark of the beast. They ***do*** "keep the commandments of God, and the faith of Jesus."

Answer (score 1):

**God Knoweth!** There will be no difficulty for God to know who the righteous are (worthy of heaven), and who the sinners are (who are left to be consigned to hell). It is so clear that Jesus described them all as **sheep or goats**! (Matthew 25:31-46)

> The foundation of God stands sure, having this seal: *The Lord knows them that are His*! (2 Timothy 2:19)

So, how does He know? There is no mistaking the answer to this question. **God looks down and examines the hearts of men**. He doesn't consider the social status, nor the appearances, neither the fame or popularity of an individual. That is all subtrafuge and a masking over of what really matters.

> The LORD said to Samuel, Look not on his countenance, nor on the height of his stature...for the LORD sees not as man sees, for man looks on the outward appearance, but the LORD looks on the heart. (2 Samuel 16:7)

The **heart** is not only the seat of affections, it is the control-center of the Will where motives are formulated. It is the source of thoughts, good or bad, which energize the tongue.

> Out of the abundance of the Heart the mouth speaks. A good man, out of the good treasure of his heart, brings forth good things; and an evil man out of the evil treasure brings forth evil things. (Matthew 12:34-35)

So on Judgment Day at the Second Coming, the righteous and the sinners will be identified by an examination of their hearts by the **all-seeing eye of God** which penetrates down into the deep recesses of the soul.

> Neither is there any creature that is not manifest in His sight; but all things are naked and opened unto the Eyes of Him with Whom we have to do. (Hebrews 4:13)

There is an abundance of verses that underscore this Providence of our omniscient God who looks on the heart of each man:

- Psalm 44:21; 94:11
- Luke 16:15
- John 10:15
- Acts 15:8 (1:24)
- 1 Corinthians 3:20
- Proverbs 4:23
- Matthew 15:17-20, Mark 7:21-23
- 1 Kings 8:39-40
- Proverbs 21:2
- Genesis 6:5
- Romans 1:21-24

This is why the Psalmist prayed, *Create in me a clean heart, and renew a right spirit within me*. And also asked God, *Examine me, O LORD, and prove me. try my reins and my heart*. (Psalm 26:2) This is also the cry of His church disciples, because **this is how God will identify those He will take to heaven!**

Answer (score 1):

From **Matthew 7:23** ESV

> "I never knew you; depart from me".

Before this question was edited what stood out was "Is it just because He knows who are His?". In short "yes". As ray grant has quoted, "The Lord knows them that are His".

This answer tries to further explore God knowing and God not knowing.

**Romans 8:16**

> "The Spirit himself bears witness with our spirit that we are children of God".

I have a friend who has dementia and does not know with his mind who is his wife after 50+ years of married life. But I believe he loves Jesus and has the peace of God which passes understanding.

When the Spirit bears witness with our spirit we have spiritual knowledge. Our minds can only know about God. When we know God and God knows us spiritually we have peace with God, peace that passes understanding with the mind.

**Matthew 7:22**

> "On that day [of judgement] many will say to me, 'Lord, Lord, did we not prophesy in your name, and cast out demons in your name, and do many mighty works in your name?" *23* And then will I declare to them, I never knew you; depart from me, you workers of lawlessness". [My bracket]

"Mighty works" can be deceptive. [Ex 7:8-13] Pharaoh's magicians threw down their rods which became serpents. Giving the impression that they had god-like power. And Satan deceives so that people misjudge their actions and say, "We ate and drank in your presence...". but the Lord's reply concludes with, "Depart from me, all you workers of evil!". [Luke 13:27].

**Romans 8:35**

> Who shall separate us from the love of Christ? Shall tribulation, or distress, or persecution, or famine, or nakedness, or danger, or sword?". [Or dementia].

**John 10:27**

> "My sheep hear my voice, and I **know** them, and they follow me". [My emphasis].

"My sheep" belong to, are loved by and are known by Jesus Christ.

Answer (score 0):

It is not given to mankind to understand the judgements of God.  God is sovereign and man is responsible.

However, it is possible to gain something of what will happen from the very scant data we are given.  Note the difference between the reaction of the righteous vs the wicked when Jesus appears:

**Righteous**

> Isa 25:9 - And it will be said in that day: “Behold, this is our God;
> We have waited for Him, and He will save us. This is the LORD; We have
> waited for Him; We will be glad and rejoice in His salvation.”

**Wicked**

> Rev 6:15-17 - Then the kings of the earth, the nobles, the commanders,
> the rich, the mighty, and every slave and free man hid in the caves
> and among the rocks of the mountains. And they said to the mountains
> and the rocks, “Fall on us and hide us from the face of the One seated
> on the throne, and from the wrath of the Lamb. For the great day of
> Their wrath has come, and who is able to withstand it?”

That is, the righteous are happy and keen to see Jesus and the wicked ask to be destroyed!  Everyone's wish is granted!

All this is predicated on the simple principle stated in -

> Ps 5:4 - ... no evil can dwell with You.

That is, for the wicked, heaven would be hell!

Answer (score 0):

The main idea of the rapture is that those who have received God's righteousness will be taken up to be with Him, while others will be left behind. Now the question is, how will God identify those who have received His righteousness? The most important thing to know is:

- **God is omniscient**

Proverbs 15:3 NKJV

> 3 The eyes of the Lord are in every place, Keeping watch on the evil
> and the good.

Jeremiah 17:10 NKJV

> 10 I, the Lord, search the heart, I test the mind, Even to give every
> man according to his ways, According to the fruit of his doings.

This being true means that God knows the hearts and faith of individuals.

It says about Abram in Genesis 15:6 NKJV

> 6 And he believed in the Lord, and He accounted it to him for
> righteousness.

Do those who received God's righteousness immediately get qualified for heaven? That is a matter of theological interpretation. It's often taught that salvation is a process and that it's a lifelong journey of faith and obedience. A process of [justification, sanctification, and glorification](https://www.gotquestions.org/justification-sanctification-glorification.html).

---

Perhaps the acronym **RAPTURE** may be useful.

**R**ighteousness: Righteousness is given by God making it easy for Him to identify who has it.

Romans 3:21-24 NIV

> 21 But now apart from the law the righteousness of God has been made
> known, to which the Law and the Prophets testify. 22 This
> **righteousness is given through faith in Jesus Christ to all who
> believe.** There is no difference between Jew and Gentile, 23 for all
> have sinned and fall short of the glory of God, 24 and all are
> justified freely by his grace through the redemption that came by
> Christ Jesus.

From this we can say that righteousness comes through faith in Jesus Christ.

**A**cceptance: We have to accept, **by faith**, God's grace and the righteousness that He offers.  Ephesians 2:8-9 explains:

> 8 **For by grace are ye saved through faith; and that not of yourselves:
> it is the gift of God**:
>
> 9 Not of works, lest any man should boast.

**P**ersonal: Christianity is about personal relationship. Allowing God to come and dine with us, but also that we may overcome. Revelation 3:20-21 NKJV

> 20 Behold, I stand at the door and knock. If anyone hears My voice and
> opens the door, I will come in to him and dine with him, and he with
> Me. 21 To him who overcomes I will grant to sit with Me on My throne,
> as I also overcame and sat down with My Father on His throne.

**T**rials: Trials will test our faith so that we may be perfect. In the last verse it talked about overcoming. James 1:2-4 NKJV

> 2 My brethren, count it all joy when you **fall into various trials**, 3
> knowing that the **testing of your faith** produces patience. 4 But let
> patience have its perfect work, **that you may be perfect and
> complete**, lacking nothing.

**U**nexpected: Since it's unexpected we are told to **be ready.** To quote the original verses from Matthew 24:36-51 NKJV

> 36 “But of that day and hour no one knows, not even the angels of
> heaven, but My Father only. 37 But as the days of Noah were, so
> also will the coming of the Son of Man be. 38 For as in the days
> before the flood, they were eating and drinking, marrying and giving
> in marriage, until the day that Noah entered the ark, 39 and did not
> know until the flood came and took them all away, so also will the
> coming of the Son of Man be. 40 Then two men will be in the field: one
> will be taken and the other left. 41 Two women will be grinding at the
> mill: one will be taken and the other left. 42 Watch therefore, for
> you do not know what hour your Lord is coming. 43 But know this,
> that if the master of the house had known what hour the thief would
> come, he would have watched and not allowed his house to be broken
> into. 44 **Therefore you also **be** ready**, for the Son of Man is coming at
> an hour you do not expect.

**R**epentance: Repentance is directly connected to righteousness. Acts 3:19 NKJV

> 19 **Repent** therefore and be converted, **that your sins may be blotted
> out**, so that times of refreshing may come from the presence of the
> Lord

1 John 1:9 NKJV

> 9 If we **confess our sins**, He is faithful and just to forgive us our
> sins and to **cleanse us from all unrighteousness**.

**E**ternity: A little rhyme: We believe to receive eternity. John 3:16 NKJV

> 16 For God so loved the world that He gave His only begotten Son, that
> **whoever believes in Him should not perish but have everlasting life**.

This is what I believe scripture says should be the identity of believers at the rapture.